# transport-guarantee CONFIDENTIAL gets ignored when there are other security-constraints present

Tags: java, https, java-ee-6, web.xml

I'm running a JAX-RS webservice and I want to protect all of it using secure connections. So I added this to my `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Prohibit unsecured HTTP</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This works all fine and dandy (with redirect from HTTP to HTTPS set up in my EAP `standalone.xml`, but I'll probably turn that off).

However, when I now want to set up BasicAuth for some resources I add another, more narrow constraint:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Project editing</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/projects</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/projects/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AUTH_USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

then suddenly **requests to these URLs -and the GET requests not even mentioned here- are happily served via HTTP.**

If I understand the [EE6 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html) correctly then in the case of several security-constraints it would combine url-patterns and http-methods. But it doesn't say anything about the transport-guarantee.

How can I solve this? HTTPS everywhere and BasicAuth on some URLs?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried these two alternatives so far:

1) Add the CONFIDENTIAL guarantee also to the second security-constraint. This helped half-way. Now POST, PUT, etc. are HTTPS-only, but GET requests to "projects" still go through on HTTP.

This could be remedied by adding a third security-constraint block that defines CONFIDENTIAL but no authentication for GET requests, but this feels intuitively wrong and incredibly hard to maintain.

2) Screw `web.xml` and reject HTTP requests using a `@WebFilter` instead:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "NoHttpFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class NoHttpFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest requ = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        if (!requ.isSecure()) {
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            resp.reset();
            resp.sendError(404, "If you're not speaking HTTPS, I'm not listening.");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

This actually works like a charm, but unfortunately it runs *after* BasicAuth, so calls to protected places will first ask for the password and then refuse entry based on the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with tomcat9.
In the tomcat global web.app I have added the CONFIDENTIAL. It works for the ROOT webapp.
But for webapp #2 it does not.

So it seems one of webapp #2's web.xml settings is overruling it.

Thoughts?

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/ui5/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>connectorview</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
```